# How to implement 'moquette' broker (MQTT Broker) in android

Tags: android, mqtt, moquette

I found a [moquette](https://github.com/technocreatives/moquette) broker(server) for Android, but unable to make it run in Android App. Can anyone help me in making a Sample App with a client using this broker in Android Studio ?

I have downloaded source code from git and added dir 'broker' 'netty_parser' and 'parser_commons' into my Android project as modules.

'moquette' document says to add following

```
include ':app', ':broker', ':netty_parser', 'parser_commons'
project(':broker').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../moquette/broker/')
project(':netty_parser').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../moquette/netty_parser/')
project(':parser_commons').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../moquette/parser_commons/')
```

into settings.gradle and then To start the server do

```
new Server().startServer();
```

It gives

```
ERROR: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Is there any other MQTT Broker (server) available for Android?

Comment: If you want help making something work you're going to have to include the code you have already tried and some description of the errors you are seeing. Edit the question to include this.

Comment: updated my question